# Using boot serialization to deserialize from a member function

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

I would like to use boost serialization to serialize/deserialize data in an instance of a class. The idea is that the class should encapsulate the data, as well as the details of serialization and deserialization. This works fine for serialization using `ar << this`, but the comparable deserialization using `ar >> this` gives a compile error

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘const q*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘const q*’
```

The following is the complete working code with my non-compilable `restoreit` function commented out. This is clearly a simplification of my real code, but the question is the same. How can I encapsulate the deserialization method into my class?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>

class q
{
  public:
    q() : f_() { }
    void setup() { f_.insert(std::make_pair(18,10)); }
    int getcount() { return f_.size(); }

    void storeit(const std::string &name)
    {
      std::ofstream ofs(name);
      boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
      ar << this;
    }
    void restoreit(const std::string &name) const
    {
      std::ifstream ifs(name);
      boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);

      // The following line gives the error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘const q*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘const q*’
      // ia >> this;
    }

  private:
    std::map<int,int> f_;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
      ar & f_;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
  const std::string name = "/tmp/blah";
  q foo;
  foo.setup();
  foo.storeit(name);

  q foo2;
  // I want to use foo2.restore(name) here
  {
    std::ifstream ifs(name);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> foo2;
  }
}
```

Comment: compiles fine on latest gcc and clang (https://godbolt.org/z/ShyPlf). What compiler/settings/boost version are you using?

Comment: This is with gcc 8.2.0 with boost 1.65. The code as posted compiles OK, but as the comment inside the `restoreit()` function says, uncommenting the line breaks the compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove *const* from `restoreit` definition. While restoring, `f_` map is being modified - you can do it only in non-const member function.

```
 void restoreit(const std::string &name)
 {
      std::ifstream ifs(name);
      boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
      ia >> *this;
 }
```